# Sql query that loops on the results

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I know this can be done and shouldnt be too hard but my brain is processing nothing right now.

I have two tables that work together for an action and a response. The response record is an action in itself so I have the below:

```
select a.[Action], b.Response, c.Action, d.Response, e.Action,
       f.Response, g.Action, h.Response  
from ValidRecruitmentAction a 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response b on a.[key] = b.[actionkey]
```

I'm trying to output all the links. So after the first action I get its response, but what about the response for that action?

I end up doing this:

```
select a.[Action], b.Response, c.Action, d.Response, e.Action,
       f.Response, g.Action, h.Response 
from ValidRecruitmentAction a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response b on a.[key] = b.[actionkey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction c on c.[Key] = b.FollowOnActionKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response d on c.[key] = d.[actionkey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction e on e.[Key] = d.FollowOnActionKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response f on e.[key] = f.[actionkey]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction g on g.[Key] = f.FollowOnActionKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response h on g.[key] = h.[actionkey]
```

I know there is a much simpler way of doing this. Can anyone remind me of how to do it, a CTE is prob required. Im looking to do this in one query, not as part of a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

My brain is not very strong today either but here is what I managed to get from it.

```
With CTE as
(
Select a.[key] as Action_key
from ValidRecruitmentAction a
where a.[action = 'My first action'

UNION ALL

Select b.FollowOnActionKey
from ValidRecruitmentAction_Response b
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Action_key = b.[actionkey]
)

Select  a.[Action], b.Response
from ValidRecruitmentAction a
    INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Action_key = a.[key]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response b on a.[key] = b.[actionkey]
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't perform brilliantly, but you can join on multiple clasues, so your ON clause could be `a.[key] =  b.[actionkey] OR c.[Key] =  b.[actionkey] OR e.[Key] ...` and so on.

In your example/situation however, I'd much rather advice you to go the UNION route.
So something like this:

```
   SELECT  a.[Action] ,
            b.Response                
    FROM    ValidRecruitmentAction a
            INNER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction_Response b ON a.[key] = b.[actionkey]
    UNION
    SELECT  a.[Action] ,               
            c.Response
    FROM    ValidRecruitmentAction a
            INNER JOIN ValidRecruitmentAction b ON a.[Key] = b.FollowOnActionKey

......insert all your remaining cases as unions
```

And then you can add WHERE clauses to each of your UNIONS for each of your cases;
And most likely make them perform much better than what you're otherwise likely to end up in trying to do everything in one join.